# Unable to query a table in hive metadata

Tags: postgresql, hive, postgresql-9.2

I am not able to query the contents of the Notification_log table.

The table is in a Postgres 9.2 instance that stores my hive metadata.

```
hive=# SELECT table_catalog, table_schema, table_name
    FROM information_schema.columns where table_name = 'NOTIFICATION_LOG';
     table_catalog | table_schema |    table_name
    ---------------+--------------+------------------
     hive          | public       | NOTIFICATION_LOG
     hive          | public       | NOTIFICATION_LOG
     hive          | public       | NOTIFICATION_LOG
     hive          | public       | NOTIFICATION_LOG
     hive          | public       | NOTIFICATION_LOG
     hive          | public       | NOTIFICATION_LOG
     hive          | public       | NOTIFICATION_LOG
     hive          | public       | NOTIFICATION_LOG
     hive          | public       | NOTIFICATION_LOG
    (9 rows)
    
    hive=# select * from NOTIFICATION_LOG;
    ERROR:  relation "notification_log" does not exist
    LINE 1: select * from NOTIFICATION_LOG;
                          ^
    hive=# show search_path;
     search_path
    -------------
     public
    (1 row)
    
    hive=#
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL names are case sensitive.  You need to surround that table name in quotes. This should work:

```sql
select * from "NOTIFICATION_LOG"
```